# What if a RabbitMQ message kills multiple worker?

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange

I am a noob on RabbitMQ. I started using it and it's serving my purpose so far. In my settings there should be around 10 consumer. I am wondering to know If a message kills multiple consumer/worker how I check that and drop that message because definitely I don't want all my worker fails because of a corrupted message. Any advice is greatly appreciated and just to update that I am using Java

Answer (score 0):

you need to have some level of error handling in your code to catch so-called "poison" messages - messages that cause problems and can't be processed.

to handle this appropriately, you'll want to set up a [Dead Letter Exchange](https://www.rabbitmq.com/dlx.html) ("dlx") for your queue. this exchange will be used to catch the poison messages, when your code recognizes the bad message.

in your error handling code, when you get a poison message you will want to `reject` the message. this will tell RabbitMQ to re-route the message through the dlx.

your dlx should have routing setup to send the poison message to a queue where an alert can be sent to you, based on a message showing up in this queue.

Comment: Thanks Derick for your valuable suggestion. I will give a short and update you.